# I've made a shorten url website. But the thing is not working that i can't include a file. It works and redirects if i go directly using url

Tags: php, mysql, url-shortener, url-masking

I've made a shorten url website. But the thing is not working. I can't include a file. It works and redirects if I go directly using a url.

my handler page code is

```
<?php

plink = explode('/',$_GET['p']);
//print_r($plink);

include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/config/file.php');

$code = $_GET['p'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shortenurl WHERE code = '$code'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows == 1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $url = $row['url'];

//  header ("Location: $url");  
}

//starts url masking
if (isset($_GET['p']))
{
    switch($_GET['p'])
    {

// pages set for common interface       
       case 'home':
       include "pages/home.php";
       break;

       case $code:
       include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/pages/redirect.php?r=$url');
       break;      

//defualt page 404 Error page is set       
       default;
       include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/errorpages/404.php');
       break;
    }
}?>
```

I have added google in database and shorten url in localhost is "site.com/AasfAS"

but I'm getting the following error

> Warning: include(C:/xampp/htdocs/core/pages/strg_rd.php?r=googlesite): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\pagehandler.php on line
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:/xampp/htdocs/core/pages/strg_rd.php?r=googlesite' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\pagehandler.php on line 
>   "

but if I go to the url `/core/pages/strg_rd.php?r=googlesite`
it redirects me to the google website
How do I solve this?

Comment: \o/ SQL Injection!

Comment: You can't pass parameters to included files like that.

Comment: Any solution? can you suggest me changed codes?

Comment: ^^ and you should be using the local file path not the web path

Comment: -1 For posting code with a SQL-injection hole in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this.

```
case $code:
       $_GET['r'] = $url;
       include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/pages/redirect.php');
       break;
```

Answer (score 0):

`include` just puts in the contents of a file into the file you're working on. There is a file called `redirect.php` (I assume), but there's no file called `redirect.php?r=...`. What you probably want to do is to simply do the redirect in the same file directly.

Since this is PHP, all you should need is to replace:

```
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/core/pages/redirect.php?r=$url');
```

with

```
header( 'Location: $url' ) ;
```

Comment: But I need to show some other details and ads on that page. I mean if you got to mysite.com/url then you will seed ads and then you will be redirected to website after few seconds.

Comment: Try this then:
`header( 'Location: /core/pages/redirect.php?r=$url' );`

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$code = $_GET['p'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shortenurl WHERE code = '$code'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Is a disaster waiting to happen.
[Fix the sql-injection hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) before your site gets pwned like so:

```
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shortenurl WHERE code = '$code'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

More info is here: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60442#60442)

Or even better drop the `mysql_` lib (It was depreciated 10 years ago!) and use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php%E2%80%8E).

See here for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php‎